# Get Records based on many Conditions in One Column

Tags: java, sql, workflow, activiti

I have an "ACT_RU_TASK"-table and an "ACT_RU_VARABILES"-table. Every task has many Variables and I want to get a group of tasks based on some Variables for Example:

ACT_RU_TASK

```
| ID     |  PROC_INST_ID_  |
-----------------------------
|   20      | 35      |
```

and

ACT_RU_VARABILES

```
| ID     |  PROC_INST_ID_  |   NAME_  | TEXT_
----------------------------------------------
|   44      | 35      |      initiator | user1
|   45      | 35      |      team      |   team1
|   46      | 35      |      status    |  0
|   47      | 35      |    profile     |  null
```

Now the Task with PROC_INST_ID_  "35" has many Variables 
so I wanna get the task or tasks based on Variables Conditions like

I wanna get the task with initiator = "user1" and team = "team1"

I write this Query but I didn't get any Result

```
SELECT *
FROM ACT_RU_TASK JOIN
     ACT_RU_VARIABLE
     ON ACT_RU_TASK.PROC_INST_ID_ = ACT_RU_VARIABLE.PROC_INST_ID_
 WHERE (ACT_RU_VARIABLE.NAME_='initiator' AND ACT_RU_VARIABLE.TEXT_='user1') AND   (ACT_RU_VARIABLE.NAME_='team' AND ACT_RU_VARIABLE.TEXT_='team1')
```

Note: I'm using Activity Framework in Java and I want to create native task Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want aggregation and `having` for filtering:

```
SELECT v.PROC_INST_ID_
FROMACT_RU_VARIABLE v
WHERE (v.NAME_ = 'initiator' AND v.TEXT_ = 'user1') OR   
      (v.NAME_ = 'team' AND v.TEXT_ = 'team1')
GROUP BY v.PROC_INST_ID_
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;   -- both attributes match
```

This checks that *both* attributes match.  You can join in additional information from other tables.  But to get the `PROC_INST_ID_` you don't need `ACT_RU_TASK`.

Comment: but can you plz Explain why you are used "OR"??

Comment: @amer_Salah . . . Because the conditions have to match on different *rows*.  With `AND`, no rows could possibly match.

Comment: why u are using count = 2 and if i add a new condition in where clause should i increase the count to 3

Comment: @amer_Salah . . . Yes.  If you had more conditions, you would add the number that need to be matched.

Comment: but if i joined with ACT_RU_TASK and put a new Condition should be added to count ??